# Which of the following statement is true?

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, time-complexity, online-algorithms

> Given two statement:
>
> A:if inputs of a problem is online, then there is faster or equal
> algorithm in view of time complexity for that problem when input is
> offline.
>
> B:if inputs of a problem is offline, then there is faster or equal
> algorithm in view of time complexity for that problem when input is
> online.
>
> Which of the following statement is true?

I think A is true because each algorithm works for online inputs then it work for a offline inputs. Now we can say A is true.
B is false because, consider online sorting algorithm and offline sorting algorithm, online algorithm have much more time complexity in ratio of offline versions.

Comment: Please credit the original source for all copied material.  See https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/referencing

Comment: Can you provide further clarification? Is it assumed that the online algorithm can only receive one input at a time? In an actual use case the sorting algorithm should be separate from the means of accessing the input. Therefore, the time complexity of sorting would be the same, regardless of input location. I do not really understand the question. If you could provide some context, that would help a lot.

Comment: Please read these Wiki pages:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_algorithm  and  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Competitive_analysis_(online_algorithm)